# sparql expecting one of "where", "using"

Tags: sparql, fuseki, turtle-rdf

I am trying to do a simple insert query in the web interface of Fuseki server. I have set the endpoint to `/update` (instead of the default `/sparql`).
I have the following query from https://www.w3.org/Submission/SPARQL-Update/:

```
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
INSERT { <http://example/egbook3> dc:title  "This is an example title" }
```

This query gets translated to:
`http://localhost:3033/dataset.html#query=PREFIX+dc%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Felements%2F1.1%2F%3E%0AINSERT+%7B+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fexample%2Fegbook3%3E+dc%3Atitle++%22This+is+an+example+title%22+%7D%0A`
or
`curl http://localhost:3033/infUpdate/update -X POST --data 'update=PREFIX+dc%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Felements%2F1.1%2F%3E%0AINSERT+%7B+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fexample%2Fegbook3%3E+dc%3Atitle++%22This+is+an+example+title%22+%7D%0A' -H 'Accept: text/plain,*/*;q=0.9'` as visible using the `Share your query` button.

The query returns the following error:

```
Error 400: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 2, column 73.
Was expecting one of:
    "where" ...
    "using" ...



Fuseki - version 2.4.0 (Build date: 2016-05-10T11:59:39+0000)
```

The error occurs both in the web interface and with `curl`. What could be the problem here? `SELECT` queries work without problems. Loading triples from a file through the web interface upload form also works. Additional question: the normal post request uses `query=` and the `curl` version uses `update=`, why is this different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The document you're referencing is the 2008 [SPARQL Update *submission*](https://www.w3.org/Submission/SPARQL-Update/), not the actual 2013 [SPARQL 1.1 recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/).  The recommendation is the actual standard, the submission is not.

An update (insert or delete) isn't a query (select, ask, construct), and the syntax for the two kinds of query aren't necessarily the same.  You note (correctly) that WHERE is optional in a select query, but that doesn't mean that it's optional in an insert.  There are two forms of insert.  There's INSERT DATA which has the syntax:

```sql
INSERT DATA  QuadData
```

and there's DELETE/INSERT which has the syntax:

```sql
( WITH IRIref )?
( ( DeleteClause InsertClause? ) | InsertClause )
( USING ( NAMED )? IRIref )*
WHERE GroupGraphPattern

DeleteClause ::= DELETE  QuadPattern 
InsertClause ::= INSERT  QuadPattern
```

So if you're using INSERT { … }, then that's the InsertClause of a DELETE/INSERT form, and you need to follow it with WHERE ….  Since you're using static data, you should probably just use the INSERT DATA form:

```sql
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
INSERT DATA { <http://example/egbook3> dc:title  "This is an example title" }
```